# Can I chain together InfoPath forms in a library using workflow?

Tags: workflow, infopath

I am wondering whether or not it is possible to utilize workflow with several InfoPath forms (library) and whether or not this is something workable.

I'm opting for splitting out into multiple InfoPath forms because of the length. Creating one multi-step/wizard InfoPath form was getting cumbersome. And I didn't want to burden the user with one large form (even though broken into steps); of course I could have gone this route and just set up some rules to point the user to the next step they didn't complete - but again this was getting overly complex. Also I don't want users to actually see the form library. Finally, I only want the user to do this once - I don't want them to go and create more than ONE instance of a form.

So I was thinking of using workflows, but I don't know whether or not I actually need to or can in this scenario.

I am thinking of creating a workflow that would have steps linking to each individual form.  Maybe have a webpart with a list that says these are the steps you have to do (Step 1, Step 2, Step 3). The list would just have a completed column (yes, no, in progress). If no/in progress then leave the "Step 1" on the webpart. If yes, then move on to the next form, etc.

I also imagine that I could "freeze" a form once it's completed by simply working with an approval methodology.

I've got a handle on the list idea with workflows, but how could I go about implementing the ability to open up the next form on the list?

Sorry, but new to SP/IP. Also, using Office 365 on an E3 plan.

Answer (score 1):

All was well until you mentioned you were using Office 365.  That means that you can't do anything custom other than sand box solutions if you needed to.  I designed a partner election form for a large firm that seems similar to this.  The easiest way to do this is to keep the forms together and simply use a wizard like interface that changes views.  I don't think you looked at the use of views with your form.  Views allows you to group relevant information together and keep the form short so the user can follow it easily.  You can save the current view in a hidden data field in the form and simply revert back to that view if the user stops half way.  That also makes it possible to help someone if they get pulled away from their computer and the form times out.
I would recommend you look at Views.
Start here:  http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/infopath-help/add-delete-and-switch-views-pages-in-a-form-HA101732801.aspx

Comment: I looked into the views in InfoPath before. While I guess I could have one workflow that "approves" the form once completed, I'm more inclined to avoid this as I need to keep on top of users to complete the forms. If they are stopped on Step 3 of a 10 step form using InfoPath views, I'm not sure how I could go about checking that OOTB. I am thinking there has to be a way to monitor this. Maybe one workflow on a separate list that has Step1, Step2, etc., and then individual workflows on each form that work with approve?